# Stata: using local variables to build a program in Stata

Tags: if-statement, statistics, regression, stata

I would like to perform a regression based on the interests of the user of the program.

For example I would like to run the following regression with the ability to change the inputs

reg prefers inSchool#female#treatment

I have multiple preference options for example math, science, arts, etc...

what i would like is something like

```
local preference = math (where I can choose the others as well)

local compareSchooling = Y
local compareGender = Y

reg preference inSchool#female#treatment

if compareSchooling=Y & compareGender=Y {
test 1.inSchool#1.female#1.treatment = 0.inSchool#0.female#1.treatment
}
```

The motivation behind this is that someone else can easily use the program to customize his/her analysis.

However, I have had a difficult time making the mechanics work.

If you have a better idea about implementation, then I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to identify a general problem within your example that requires a program.

Also, when you ask about a Stata program, a Stata programmer tends to imagine that you expect to write `program` and that way to define a new command, but it's not at all obvious that you really need to write a new command here.

The example I take to be that `regress` and `test` could be run repeatedly for different variables.

But some details are obscure. What is `Y`? Or is it just a way of indicating "Yes"? If you were to run this interactively, the use of local macros would be futile, as you would just be putting a name into a local macro and taking it out again.

If you do write a program, then you need to document it with a help file to explain what it does, or minimally otherwise. For what purpose? So, that a user (you or someone else) can repeat two commands with different details? The gain there is not clear.

As far I understand your problem, the main need is not a program at all, but

1. To put repeated commands in a do-file and allow that do-file to take arguments. That's a much underestimated possibility. See [the [U] manual, 16.4](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/u.pdf)
2. To learn about looping over variables with a `foreach` loop.

Note: "local variables" is not standard Stata terminology; they would always be called "local macros". In Stata a variable is a column in the dataset.

Comment: I like your idea of using the do file to pass arguments. Would I then use an if statement to capture the case the user is interested in based on the parameter? I could write out all of the regressions and f-tests, but the goal of the do file is to only represent the comparisons that interest the user. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also is there such a thing as an else if statement in STATA? I have experience writing in python, and I'm finding this kind of coding a bit challenging.

Comment: On `else` etc. do read `help ifcmd`. Otherwise please ask a new question with good detail and some attempt at code. If the users don't know Stata, you are going to have to devise ways of letting them specify what interests them.  Spelling is "Stata".